# Empty Plot in Python Matplotlib, dont know why

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I'm trying to plot some data, which I can easily print out. When I plot the data in any way a blank plot appears. I dont fully understand why this is happening as the dataframe is full of data, and the plotting doesnt raise any errors. Below is my code. I've also attached an image of the blank/empty plot below.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Read the data from "Cosmic.csv"
df = pd.read_csv("Cosmic.csv")

# Filter rows for a specific day
specific_day = '2021-08-13'  # Replace this with the desired date
specific_day_df = df[df['date'] == specific_day]

# Define the latitude and longitude of the specific point
specific_lat =  15 # Replace with actual latitude
specific_lon = 48  # Replace with actual longitude

# Create a box around the specific point
latitude_range = [specific_lat - 2000, specific_lat + 2000]
longitude_range = [specific_lon - 2000, specific_lon + 200]
box_df = specific_day_df[
    (specific_day_df['Latitude'] >= latitude_range[0]) & (specific_day_df['Latitude'] <= latitude_range[1]) &
    (specific_day_df['Longitude'] >= longitude_range[0]) & (specific_day_df['Longitude'] <= longitude_range[1])]

# Create a heatmap
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))


# altitude_bins = pd.interval_range(start=filtered_data['Altitude'].min(), 
 #                                     end=filtered_data['Altitude'].max() + 10, 
  #                                    freq=10)
  

# df['altitude_bin'] = pd.cut(filtered_data['Altitude'], bins=altitude_bins)


# mean_density = df.groupby(['altitude_bin', 'date_bin'])['Electron_Density'].mean().unstack()

# Convert bin labels to dates for plotting
# mean_density.columns = mean_density.columns.map(lambda x: x.mid.strftime('%m/%d'))



print("Not Pivoted Data already filtered:")
print(box_df)

print("Pivoted Data for Plotting:")
print(box_df.pivot_table(values='Electron_Density', index='Altitude', columns='date', aggfunc='mean'))

sns.heatmap(box_df.pivot_table(values='Electron_Density', index='Altitude', columns='date', aggfunc='mean'),
           cmap='jet', linewidths=0.5)

# sns.heatmap(mean_density)

plt.axhline(y=specific_day_df['Altitude'].min(), linestyle='--', color='k')
plt.axvline(x=specific_day_df['date'].iloc[0], linestyle='--', color='k')

plt.xlabel('Date', fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Altitude in km', fontweight='bold')
plt.title('Electron Density Heatmap', fontweight='bold')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

plt.show()
```

Here is the output stream and blank plot:

```
 Not Pivoted Data already filtered:
        Unnamed: 0.3  Unnamed: 0.2  Unnamed: 0.1  Unnamed: 0  Day   Latitude  \
277461        277461      14139589      14140062    14140062  225  15.002479  
277464        277464      14139592      14140065    14140065  225  15.204655   
277465        277465      14139593      14140066    14140066  225  15.272005   
...              ...           ...           ...         ...  ...        ...   
306369        306369      15750990      15751793    15751793  225  15.117569     
306373        306373      15750994      15751797    15751797  225  15.022529   

        Longitude   Altitude  Electron_Density        TEC  \
277461 -51.131245  463.24896         49245.555  10.842576   
277465 -51.455490  467.51334         55565.457  10.787354   
...           ...        ...               ...        ...   
306369 -83.494180  492.12985        106565.130  14.947100     
306373 -83.278440  496.97370        102364.370  13.715951   

        Occultation_Azimuth        date        Altitude_Bin  mean_density  
277461          -141.431850  2021-08-13  [460.001, 470.001)  96827.112941  
277462          -141.466920  2021-08-13  [460.001, 470.001)  96827.112941
...                     ...         ...                 ...           ...  
306373            38.950077  2021-08-13  [490.001, 500.001)  74717.005703  

[28913 rows x 14 columns]
Pivoted Data for Plotting:
date        2021-08-13
Altitude              
100.04126    9397.4210
100.14729  147425.3300
100.18883    9091.6930
...                ...
546.82135   26094.6430
546.87100   10054.5460
546.92224    2458.5593
```

[image]

Comment: One of the problems is that `sns.heatmap` uses "categorical" coordinates, internally using the numbers `0, 1, 2, ...` to plot).  `axvline` and `axhline` use numeric coordinates.  You could try to first leave those two functions out, and afterward try to calculate their desired position in categorical coordinates. As you only seem to have one column, the  `axvline` can't be put in a good spot.